# Tangled in generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have classes A, B with `B extends A`
I have interface defined as

```
public interface MyProcessor<EVENT> {
     void processEvent(EVENT event);
}
```

I have two implementations

```
public class EventAProcessor implements EventProcessor<A> {
    @Override
    public void processEvent(A a) {
}
public class EventBProcessor implements EventProcessor<B> {
    @Override
    public void processEvent(B b) {
}
```

there is common processing so I decided to extend BProcessor from Aprocessor

```
public class EventBProcessor extends EventAProcessor implements EventProcessor<B> {

    }
```

This is where it fails with the message

```
 MyProcessor cannot be inherited with different arguments: <A> and <B>
```

I have other solutions to workaround my problem, but just wondering, how to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should introduce an abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEventProcessor<EVENT> 
  implements EventProcessor<EVENT> {

  // Put your common logic here
}
```

Your other classes will then inherit common functionality as such:

```
public class EventAProcessor extends AbstractEventProcessor<A> {}
public class EventBProcessor extends AbstractEventProcessor<B> {}
```

This doesn't necessarily have to do with generics. It's a general way to approch polymorphism in object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 4):

Don't make `EventBProcessor` extend `EventAProcessor` as it's not an `is-a` relationship. Reuse the functions you need either by pulling them into a common abstract class, or in a separate helper class that you reuse by composition. It's not always the best option to reuse through inheritance.

Comment: In particular, an `EventBProcessor` can _only_ handle `B`s, where an `EventAProcessor` can handle all `A`s, including `B`s.  That's why they're not in an "is-a" relationship.

Comment: Nice clarification. It's a covariance-contravariance mismatch.

Comment: Indeed.  The traditional mnemonic is Josh Bloch's "PECS" acronym: producer extends, consumer super.  `EventProcessor` is a "consumer," so if `B super A`, then an `EventProcessor<A>` can be used as an `EventProcessor<B>`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Sometimes I like to explain it in terms of promises. `B extends A` means that it gives all promises of `A`, plus additional ones. `EventProcessor<B>`, however, gives **less** promises than `EventProcessor<A>`. That's contravariance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse code through inheritance, the following should be OK:

```
public abstract AbstractEventAProcessor<T extends A> implements EventProcessor<T> {
    // common methods
}

public class EventAProcessor extends AbstractEventAProcessor<A> {
    @Override
    public void processEvent(A a) { ... }
}

public class EventBProcessor extends AbstractEventAProcessor<B> {
    @Override
    public void processEvent(B b) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I see.  This factors out the common code, even if it doesn't add the subclass relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the interface has anything to do with either of your implementations.  Neither of them implements the `MyProcessor` interface.

You also don't show any hierarchy for the Event class.  What makes you think you can have different Event types with this arrangement?

Here's how I might do it:

```
public interface Event {
    String getName();
}

public interface EventProcessor<T extends Event> {
    void process(T event);
}
```

You don't need different `EventProcessor` implementations this way - the generic should be able to differentiate between different `Event` types.  You'll only need a custom implementation if the `process()` method needs to change by type.  You might way to think about a Visitor pattern if it does.

Comment: All my events don't extend from common base, So cant use this, but I think its right to do so, but again, I dont own the producing system.

Answer (score 0):

Add a shared "common" generic ancestor that requires A or a subclass thereof.

```
public abstract class ACommonProcessor<AEvent extends A> implements MyProcessor<AEvent> {
    ...
    // shared code goes here
}

public class EventBProcessor extends ACommonProcessor<B> {
    ...
    // B-specific code goes here
}

public class EventAProcessor extends ACommonProcessor<A> {
    ...
    // etc
}
```